# PHP DateTime Issue: Call to a member function format() on boolean

Tags: php, date, datetime-format, fatal-error

I know this has been beaten to death on here, and I've read through all the posts over the years, but cannot find a solution. I'm trying to rearrange a date and have used various methods, but keep getting this error.

```
$dateMDY    = trim($dateTime2[1]);
$dateMDYp   = preg_replace("~(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)~", "$1-$2-$3", $dateMDY);

echo "dateMDY: '".$dateMDY."'<br /><br /><br />\n";
echo "dateMDYp: '".$dateMDYp."'<br /><br /><br />\n";

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/y', '12/2/17');
echo "dt: '".$dt->format('Y-m-d')."'<br />\n"; 
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('n-j-y', '12-2-17');
echo "dt2: '".$dt2->format('Y-m-d')."'<br />\n";
$dt3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/y', $dateMDY);
echo "dt3: '".$dt3->format('Y-m-d')."'<br />\n";
$dt4 = DateTime::createFromFormat('n-j-y', $dateMDYp);
echo "dt4: '".$dt4->format('Y-m-d')."'<br />\n";
```

This throws the following:

```
dateMDY: '12/2/17'
dateMDYp: '12-2-17'
dt: '2017-12-02'
dt2: '2017-12-02'

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean
```

I must be missing something very simple, as DateTime:: has to be sending false for some reason, yet the format that is echoed when I call the variable shows the correct number.

PHP v.7.1.0

Comment: what do you get when you `var_dump($dt3)` ?

Comment: @Mehrdad Dastgir  I get "boolean false" when I var_dump($dt3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've solved the issue. I started var_dump-ing all the variables until I noticed something...

```
C:\wamp64\www\a\datetime.php:47:string '12/2/17</URD>' (length=13)
```

While print and echo show only '12/2/17', var_dump shows trailing data "</URD>" which is a tag I have in the database table I'm calling from. I'm not sure why the complete data isn't being shown on print or echo, but a simple str_replace to my $dateMDY variable removed the unseen </URD> and now prints the correct format.

Hopefully this can help someone in the future who may be scratching their heads at unseen data being attached to their variables!

Thanks to @Mehrdad Dastgir for illuminating an idea for me.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime::createFromFormat` return `false` on error ([more here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)).

That's why when you call `->format` you get

> `Call to a member function format() on boolean`

to see the error you can call `DateTime::getLastErrors`. ([DateTime::getLastErrors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php))

Comment: I tried using DateTime::getLastErrors through multiple examples and it doesn't print anything when I use the variable, only the same error,When I use the '12-2-17' textual format, nothing is thrown. When I mess with the format, it gives me the expected warnings.